# Is there any way to stop DrJava without losing the error messages in the interactions pane?

Tags: java, reset, drjava

I'm having an issue right now with some runaway code (not quite sure if it's stuck in a loop) and I'd like to be able to see the error messages DrJava is giving. However, when I click the "Reset" button, it wipes all the information from the interactions pane, including the error messages. Apart from writing an email to the developers asking them to fix this feature, is there any way to stop DrJava without resetting? Should I just try to switch to Eclipse?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use DrJava with Eclipse, there is a plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can stop Dr. Java from clearing the interactions pane, but you can save the contents of the interactions pane during an infinite loop.

This can be done by going to Tools -> Interactions & Console -> Save Copy of Interactions

Hope this is helpful